# query to fetch the all table name where there is a certain column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to fetch all tables that have for example a column called `CreatedBy`in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Your question had more extra stuff than something that was actually related to your question so I rewrote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sql Server you can get this by looking at the `sys.columns` table

```
  use DB_MAST_AERRE
  select 
         OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) AS SchemaName,
         object_name(object_id) AS TableName
         from 
            sys.columns
            where name = 'CreatedBy'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use [AdventureWorks2014]
go

declare @columnname varchar(50)
set @columnname='CreatedBy'

select a.name as columnname ,b.name as tablename
from sys.columns a
inner join sys.tables b
on a.object_id=b.object_id
where a.name like '%'+@columnname+'%'
```